# Best way to store key with array of value

Tags: java, collections, groovy

I'm returning some datas which have to be treated after. It's a couple key/value with the value being an array. I'm working on a POC with groovy and plan to do it in Java; This is why there is the LinkedHashMap which corresponds to the groovy map implementation. This is the solution for the moment :

```
LinkedHashMap<EntityKey, ArrayList<EntityValue>> results = new LinkedHashMap<EntityKey, ArrayList<EntityValue>>();
```

And as I'm getting a list of this I would like to know if there is a way to improve it.

Comment: This question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use a Multimap: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap

Which removes the hassle of checking if the Array exists etc...

Comment: Hey thanks, I needed this for something else too !

Answer (score 0):

So a `Map<EntityKey, List<EntityValue>>` is the best representation of your data?

Then, **perfect**, go with it.

If it is clear what it is for you, why use something else?

Comment: I also thought about it, but it's always good to learn other ways. Icewind learnt me something ;)

Comment: He taught you something :) http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/teach Anyway! I agree with Vakh; you should avoid questions that can lead to very broad answers. If something is working for you then SO is not really a place for the question, if you have a solution and you know it won't work for you then you can bring very narrow details of why it doesn't work for you and what characteristics your solution needs to provide. If your current solution does indeed fulfill your needs then go on with it :)

Comment: No I refuse your correction ;)
I didn't know codereview, i'll know this it next time (second thing I learnt today ;) )